# installing boost 1.42 (or any other version) on Vista with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, boost, build-process

I want to install boost library on ma PC with Vista and Visual Studio 2010.

First of all a downloaded boost 1.42 from official site and unpacked to c:\boost_1_42_0
Then I invoked bootstrap.bat but i get some errors:

```
c:\boost_1_42_0>bootstrap.bat
Building Boost.Jam build engine

Failed to build Boost.Jam build engine.
Please consult bjam.log for furter diagnostics.

You can try to obtain a prebuilt binary from

   http://sf.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=7586&package_id=72941

Also, you can file an issue at http://svn.boost.org
Please attach bjam.log in that case.
```

in bjam.log I found:

```
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.
ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder.
###
### Using 'vc10' toolset.
###

c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src>if exist bootstrap rd /S /Q bootstrap

c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src>md bootstrap

c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src>cl /nologo /RTC1 /Zi /MTd /Fobootstrap/
/Fdbootstrap/ -DNT -DYYDEBUG -wd4996 kernel32.lib advapi32.lib
user32.lib /Febootstrap\jam0  command.c compile.c debug.c execnt.c
expand.c filent.c glob.c hash.c hdrmacro.c headers.c jam.c jambase.c
jamgram.c lists.c make.c make1.c newstr.c option.c output.c parse.c
pathunix.c regexp.c rules.c scan.c search.c subst.c timestamp.c
variable.c modules.c strings.c filesys.c builtins.c pwd.c class.c
w32_getreg.c native.c modules/set.c modules/path.c modules/regex.c
modules/property-set.c modules/sequence.c modules/order.c
command.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
compile.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
debug.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
execnt.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
expand.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
filent.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
glob.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
hash.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
hdrmacro.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
headers.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
jam.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
jambase.c
jamgram.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
lists.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
make.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
make1.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
newstr.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
option.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
output.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
parse.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
Generating Code...
Compiling...
pathunix.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
regexp.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
rules.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
scan.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
search.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
subst.c
subst.c(1) : fatal error C1034: stddef.h: no include path set
timestamp.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
variable.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
modules.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
strings.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
filesys.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
builtins.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
pwd.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
class.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\strings.h(8) : fatal error C1034:
stddef.h: no include path set
w32_getreg.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
native.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
set.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
path.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
regex.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
property-set.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
Generating Code...
Compiling...
sequence.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
order.c
c:\boost_1_42_0\tools\jam\src\jam.h(88) : fatal error C1034: fcntl.h:
no include path set
Generating Code...
```

So I decided to download bjam binary, and save it to c:\boost_1_42_0

Then I invoked

> c:\boost_1_42_0>bjam --toolset=msvc --build-type=complete stage

But i get many errors:

```
    call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 >n
ul
cl /Zm800 -nologo @"bin.v2\libs\wave\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\runtime-l
ink-static\token_ids.obj.rsp"

...failed compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\wave\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\runti
me-link-static\token_ids.obj...
compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\wave\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\runtime-link-st
atic\wave_config_constant.obj
wave_config_constant.cpp
libs\wave\src\wave_config_constant.cpp(17) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open incl
ude file: 'cstring': No such file or directory

    call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 >n
ul
cl /Zm800 -nologo @"bin.v2\libs\wave\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\runtime-l
ink-static\wave_config_constant.obj.rsp"

...failed compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\wave\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\runti
me-link-static\wave_config_constant.obj...
common.mkdir bin.v2\libs\wave\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\runtime-link-sta
tic\cpplexer
common.mkdir bin.v2\libs\wave\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\runtime-link-sta
tic\cpplexer\re2clex
compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\wave\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\runtime-link-st
atic\cpplexer\re2clex\aq.obj
aq.cpp
libs\wave\src\cpplexer\re2clex\aq.cpp(16) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open inclu
de file: 'cstdlib': No such file or directory

    call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 >n
ul
cl /Zm800 -nologo @"bin.v2\libs\wave\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\runtime-l
ink-static\cpplexer\re2clex\aq.obj.rsp"

...failed compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\wave\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\runti
me-link-static\cpplexer\re2clex\aq.obj...
compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\wave\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\runtime-link-st
atic\cpplexer\re2clex\cpp_re.obj
cpp_re.cpp
libs\wave\src\cpplexer\re2clex\cpp_re.cpp(20) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open i
nclude file: 'ctime': No such file or directory

    call "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x86 >n
ul
cl /Zm800 -nologo @"bin.v2\libs\wave\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\runtime-l
ink-static\cpplexer\re2clex\cpp_re.obj.rsp"

...failed compile-c-c++ bin.v2\libs\wave\build\msvc-10.0\debug\link-static\runti
me-link-static\cpplexer\re2clex\cpp_re.obj...
...skipped libboost_wave-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib for lack of instantiate_cpp_exprgrammar.obj...
...skipped libboost_wave-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib for lack of libboost_wave-vc100
-sgd-1_42.lib...
...skipped libboost_date_time-vc100-sgd.lib for lack of 
libboost_date_time-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib...
...skipped libboost_system-vc100-sgd.lib for lack of lib
boost_system-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib...
...skipped libboost_filesystem-vc100-sgd.lib for lack of libboost_filesystem-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib...
...skipped libboost_regex-vc100-sgd.lib for lack of libb
oost_regex-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib...
...skipped libboost_graph-vc100-sgd.lib for lack of libb
oost_graph-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib...
...skipped libboost_iostreams-vc100-sgd.lib for lack of 
libboost_iostreams-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib...
...skipped libboost_math_tr1-vc100-sgd.lib for lack of l
ibboost_math_tr1-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib...
...skipped libboost_math_tr1f-vc100-sgd.lib for lack of 
libboost_math_tr1f-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib...
...skipped libboost_math_tr1l-vc100-sgd.lib for lack of 
libboost_math_tr1l-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib...
...skipped libboost_math_c99-vc100-sgd.lib for lack of l
ibboost_math_c99-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib...
...skipped libboost_math_c99f-vc100-sgd.lib for lack of 
libboost_math_c99f-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib...
...skipped libboost_math_c99l-vc100-sgd.lib for lack of 
libboost_math_c99l-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib...
...skipped libboost_program_options-vc100-sgd.lib for lack of libboost_program_options-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib...
...skipped libboost_python-vc100-sgd.lib for lack of lib
boost_python-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib...
...skipped libboost_serialization-vc100-sgd.lib for lack of libboost_serialization-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib...
...skipped libboost_wserialization-vc100-sgd.lib for lack of libboost_wserialization-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib...
...skipped libboost_signals-vc100-sgd.lib for lack of li
bboost_signals-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib...
...skipped libboost_prg_exec_monitor-vc100-sgd.lib for lack of libboost_prg_exec_monitor-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib...
...skipped libboost_test_exec_monitor-vc100-sgd.lib for lack of libboost_test_exec_monitor-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib...
...skipped libboost_unit_test_framework-vc100-sgd.lib for lack of libboost_unit_test_framework-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib...
...skipped libboost_wave-vc100-sgd.lib for lack of libbo
ost_wave-vc100-sgd-1_42.lib...
...failed updating 1176 targets...
...skipped 1629 targets...
...updated 276 targets...
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does the same happen if you run bjam from a regular command prompt, rather than the VS one? Also, do the same errors occur if you try with 1.43? VS2010 wasn't out when 1.42 was released, so there may have been compatibility fixes added to 1.43

Answer (score 5):

I believe the errors you are seeing are because your environment (PATH...) isn't set up properly.

Unlike Unix-ish OSes, Windows likes to keep the system PATH clean. Visual studio adds an entry to the start menu named "Visual Studio CMD", which sets up everything for you.

You should use this command prompt and then `cd` to the location of the boost source code, then run bootstrap.bat.

Comment: in my experience though, bjam takes care of setting up the path for you. (Can see in the build log it calls `vcvarsall.bat` which sets all the VS environment variables)

Answer (score 0):

You can download pre-build boost from http://www.boostpro.com/download/

Comment: No I can't. These binaries are compiled for Visual Studio 2003, Visual Studio 2005, Visual Studio 2008 but not for Visual Studio 2010. And that's just not the case because i was asking how to build it from sources. Then i can for example configure boost::python for python version i use.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your VS is not fully/properly installed. In particular, this message is concerning:

```
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.
ERROR: Cannot determine the location of the VS Common Tools folder.
```

I suggest that you create a .cpp file that does nothing but

```
#include <fcntl.h>
```

and then make this file compilable with "cl" invocation -- preferably in "VS command prompt". You might have to reinstall VS or Platform SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run the VS 2010 Express command prompt as administrator and "bootstrap" worked. Before, it was failing in the way op described.